# Django login_required - user already already authenicated

Tags: django, python-2.7, authentication, login-required

I'm trying to get the login_required decoration in django working.

My view looks like this

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        print 'in'
    else:
        print 'out'
    context = {'test_obj': 'Testing Testing 123'}
    return render(request, 'web_copo/index.html', context)
```

and my settings.py like this

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'web_co',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project_copo.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project_copo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'co_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'Host': '127.0.0.1',
        'Port': '',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                               "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                               "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                               "django.core.context_processors.media",
                               "django.core.context_processors.static",
                               "django.core.context_processors.tz",
                               "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                               'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
```

every time I navigate to the page, it lets me straight in. Also it prints 'in', meaning that django thinks my user is already logged in. Since I haven't logged in, I don't why this is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try printing `request.user`.

Comment: ok...its logged in 'root' which is my only user and is a superuser. Why has it automatically logged in root, and how do I disable this behaviour?

Comment: It does not 'log in' as root by default...maybe you logged a while ago and still gets the same user. Try login out or running it in chrome incog mode to avoid that.

Comment: try clearing cache of the browser

Comment: Ahh thats it. I had logged in to the admin console. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're logged in as root, try going to your admin and log out.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try your browser's incognito window/tab. That way you will have new session in each window/tab.